# Can a number written only with zeros, threes, fives, sevens and eights be a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

> Can a number written only with zeros, threes, fives, sevens, and eights be a perfect square?

I've tried to look at the residues modulo $3$ and $9$ with the sum of the numbers, but I've gotten no useful conclusions, and now I got no idea what I can do. Please, help me solve it!

Comment: If there is, there must be one which ends in $5.$ Show that isn't possible.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, why can't we have a perfect square that does not end with 5? Why did you say that there "must" be one which ends with 5?

Comment: You can have one that ends in $0,$ but the last non-zero digit must be $5.$ So the numbers that end in non-zero digits must end in $5.$ (However, there is one such square, since $0$ is a square, and only uses those digits.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, unfortunately I vaguely understand your hints right now. I can't understand the reason why you choose exactly this "5" digit

Comment: To understand Thomas Andrews hint look at the last digits of squares.

Comment: @jjagmath, okay : if number contains number 5 it ends with it because every perfect square with 5 must end with 5, now I get it

Comment: Not exactly. The point is that no square ends in $2$,$3$,$7$ or $8$.

Comment: @jjagmath, To prove that, can we look at the possible remains of the full square modulo 10? If we go over them, it’s like he can’t have the numbers as his leftovers?

Comment: @jjagmath, yes, now I can prove that no square ends in 2, 3, 7 or 8

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I'm sorry for my stupidness, but after realizing that a perfect square does not finish with 2, 3, 7, 8 and can finish only in 5 or 0 but I still can't understand your first and second messages

Comment: @jjagmath, now I understand everything except of "However, there is one such square, since 0 is a square, and only uses those digits." I guess we should show that there is no such perfect squares at all, and I can't understand the meaning of "there is one such square"

Comment: Your last comment leads to the old question, [is $0$ a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3924495/89922)?

Comment: Thomas Andrews observed that the answer to your question is "Yes", there exists a perfect square that use those digits: $0$.

Comment: [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395675/is-there-a-perfect-square-other-than-9-all-of-whose-digits-are-7-8-or-9)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let’s say there is such a square $n$ that is entirely comprised of the digits $0,3, 5,7$ and $8$. Then $n \pmod {10}$ would have to be one of $0,3,5,7$ or $8$.
To make answering this question a little easier, let’s ignore the case when $0 \equiv n \pmod {10}$ for right now.

Let’s see what happens when we square all digits from $1$ to $9 \pmod {10}$.

$1^2 \equiv 9^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {10} \\
2^2 \equiv 8^2 \equiv 4 \pmod {10} \\
3^2 \equiv 7^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {10} \\
4^2 \equiv 6^2 \equiv 6 \pmod {10} \\
5^2 \equiv 5 \pmod {10}$

As we can see, squaring any digit other than $5$ yields an ending digit outside of your specified criteria. Thus if $n$ exists, it must end in $5$.

Well, what about the other digits? Suppose $n=m^2$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $m$ must end in $5$ and so it can be written as $10a+5$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$ (namely $a= \frac{m-5}{10}$). Notice that
$$m^2= (10a+5)^2 = 100a^2+ 100a + 25$$
Thus $n = m^2 \equiv 25 \pmod{100}$, but as per your restrictions, $n$ cannot contain the digit $2$ and hence cannot end in $5$.

Lastly, we consider when $n$ ends in $0$. If $n= 0$ then the answer is trivial so we’ll suppose $n \neq 0$. Then, as shown above, $n$ cannot end in $1, \dots, 9$. So then $n$ must end in $0$. Again we consider $n=m^2$ and see that $m$ can be written as $10a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$. This time $m^2=(10a)^2=100a^2$. So again we are faced with the same problem, since the digits of $a^2$ must be within your requirements.

I hope this suffices to answer your question!

Comment: A typesetting hint:  Use `n \pmod {10}` to get the spacing right for $n \pmod {10}$.

Comment: Thank you for such a concise and comprehensible answer